# How to apply Doppler's effect in sound when source or observer is accelerating?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, acoustics, doppler-effect

Q)A parachutist jumps from the top of a very high tower with a siren of frequency 800 Hz on his
back. Assume his initial velocity to be zero. After falling freely for 12s, he observes that the
frequency of sound heard by him reflected from level ground below him is differing by 700 Hz
w.r.t. the original frequency. What was the height of tower? Velocity of sound in air is 330 m/s, and
g = 10 m/s2

---

For reflection of sound wave from ground, once the source will be accelerating(when wave is approaching the ground) and once the observer is accelerating(when the reflected wave is approaching the parachutist).Also the velocity of parachutist is comparable to the velocity of sound. How do I use Doppler's effect in such a situation?

---

Also can we find a general formula for
a)accelerating source
b)accelerating observer?

Answer (score 1):

> A parachutist jumps from the top of a very high tower with a siren of frequency $800$Hz on his back. Assume his initial velocity to be zero. After falling freely for $12$s, he observes that the frequency of the sound heard by him reflected from the level ground below him is differing by $700$Hz
> w.r.t. the original frequency. What is the height of the tower? Velocity of sound in air is $330$m/s, and $g = 10$m/s$^2$.

Say that the sound which is going to be heard by the parachutist at $t=12s$ was emitted at $t=t_1$. Then, an imaginary observer at the ground would hear the sound of $f=f_1$. So,
$$\frac{f_1}{800}=\left(\frac{330}{330-gt_1}\right)\tag{1}$$
Now, the sound with $f=f_1$ is going to be heard by the parachutist as that of $f=f_2$. So,
$$\frac{f_2}{f_1}=\left(\frac{330+12g}{330}\right)\tag{2}$$
Multiplying $(1)$ and $(2)$ gives
$$\frac{f_2}{800}=\left(\frac{330+12g}{330-gt_1}\right)\tag{3}$$
where $f_2=(800\pm700)\text{Hz}\Rightarrow f_2=1500\text{Hz}$, for the RHS of $(3)>1$.
\begin{align*}
\Rightarrow \frac{15}{8}&=\left(\frac{330+12g}{330-gt_1}\right)\\
\frac{15}{8}&=\left(\frac{450}{330-10t_1}\right)\\
t_1&=9s\\
\Rightarrow d_1&=\frac12gt_1^2=405m\\
\Rightarrow d_2&=ut_1+\frac12g(12-t_1)^2=315m&(\because u=9t_1)\\
d_2+2d_3&=330\times(12-t_1)=990m&(\because \text{distance travelled by sound in }t=12-t_1=3s)\\
\Rightarrow d_3&=337.5m\\
\Rightarrow H&=1057.5m
\end{align*}
[image]